# using __call() to pass parameters to a method that takes more than one but not as an array

Tags: php

I have created a __call() method to load methods dynamically. One problem I want to work around is the fact that the __call() makes an array of all the parameters passed from the call. this is my code

```
public function __call($method, $params)
{
    if (count($params) <= 1)
            $params = $params[0];

    foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $property => $value) {

        $class = '\\System\\' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', '', $property)) . '_Helper';

        if (strpos($method, str_replace('_', '', $property)) !== false) {

            if (!in_array($class, get_declared_classes()))
                $this->$property = new $class($params);

            $error = $method . ' doesn\'t exist in class ' . $class;

            return (method_exists($class, $method) ? $this->$property->$method($params) : $error);
        }
    }
}
```

the issue is that i can account for the array only having one parameter, but some of my methods take in more than one parameter which limits the dynamic nature of the __call() method.

how can I convert an array into a dynamically passed method parameter?

so

```
array(0 => 'stuff1', 1 => 'stuff2');
```

can passed as

```
$this->->helper->test($param1, $param2);
```

instead of

```
$this->helper->test($params);
```

with the current design I need to access parameters like

```
public function test($params)
{
    print_r($params);
    echo $param[0];
}
```

but I want the use it in a traditional manner like

```
public function test($param1, $param2)
{
    echo $para1 . " " . $param2;
}
```

keeping in mind that some methods take more than 2 parameters, the reason being is that if i include traditional style class methods not created by me I would need to convert all the parameter calls into a array index pointer.

EDIT:

as per an answer

```
return (method_exists($class, $method) ? call_user_func_array(array($this->$property, $method), $params) : $error);
```

will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of php 5.6, you can unpack the arguments via the new [splat operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) like this:

```
public function __call($method, $params) {
    $result = $this->helper->$method(...$params);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Can be done with [call_user_func_array](http://docs.php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
call_user_func_array( array($this->$property, $method), $params );
```

or via [reflection](http://docs.php.net/reflection)

Comment: I would just return that instead of calling the method like i had originally?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [`call_user_func_array()`](http://us.php.net/call_user_func_array). [This comment](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#100794) is useful too.

(Also, consider throwing exceptions instead of just returning error strings.)

Comment: yup, i'm still designing my functions before i get to the exceptions =)